# XCODE: Linking issue when using string streams <sstream>

Tags: c++, xcode, stringstream

I don't understand why XCode is running into a linking issue when using

```
    string create_base_uri(string host, int port, string dbname){
      std::ostringstream ostr; //output string stream
      ostr << port; //use the string stream just like cout,
      string port_string = ostr.str();
      return "http://" + host + ":" + port_string + "/" + dbname;
}
```

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "CouchServer::create_base_uri(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, int, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >)", referenced from:
>         CouchServer::get_document_by_id(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >) in couch_server.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Is `create_base_uri` defined in the class `CouchServer`? It doesn't look like it in the example you've given.

Comment: Yes. private:
    string create_base_uri(string host, int port, string dbname);

Comment: No, that's the declaration. The definition needs to be `string CouchServer::create_base_uri(string host, int port, string dbname) { //...`

Comment: if I comment out lines that use sstream it works

Comment: Your right! I'm a dork

Comment: If you make an answer I'll check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the member function relative to the class:

```
string CouchServer::create_base_uri(string host, int port, string dbname) {
    //..
}
```

Instead, you're defining a free function:

```
string create_base_uri(string host, int port, string dbname) {
    //..
}
```

Interestingly, it compiles as it doesn't refer to any other members of the class. It may be better to actually make it a free function! If it is currently a private member you can put it in an anonymous namespace instead. If it's useful in other places, you could make it into a utility function.